# Convert multiple JSON files and print multiple csv files

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have some code that will take a bunch of JSON files and parse and convert them to csv.  I have made it work by taking several JSON files (the output runs on command prompt) but I can't figure out how to make it print a csv file for each given JSON file it starts with.

So here is what I have.  At the moment it works just fine one file at a time but as I have hundreds, it's necessary to automate it more so i can handle batches.

All help greatly appreciated. My attempts to piece other people's suggestions to this have not worked :/

```
import json

file_list = ['file.txt', 'file2.txt'] #insert filename(s) here
for x in range(len(file_list)):
    with open(file_list[x], 'r') as f:
        distros_dict = json.load(f)

    for distro in distros_dict:
        print (str(distro['timestamp'])+ ','+ str(distro['value']))
```

Comment: You should use pandas to help you. You can load your json to a pandas DataFrame ( https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html) and then save the DataFrame as csv : df.to_csv("/PATH/TO/FILE.csv",index=False)

Comment: Python has a csv module.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas package.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(distros_dict ['timestamp']['value'])
```

You dont need to use loop in json